# How do I print out a 2-D array of the alphabet using a keyword?

Tags: c++

So I was given the task to print out a 2-D array which is 5x5 having each letter of the alphabet in each of the locations of the array. I am supposed to use a keyword and print that in the rows of the 2-D array, then print out the rest of the letters of the alphabet. The letters should only be printed once in the whole array and 'Z' is excluded.

Not to good but this is what I have so far:

```
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool correct_keyword(char);

int main()
{
    ifstream fin ("infile.txt");
    char array[5][5];
    char i, keyword;
    bool correct;

    cout << "Type in the key word: " << endl;
    cin >> keyword;
    correct_keyword(keyword);

        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            {
                keyword= array[row][col];
            }
        }
        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 0; col < 5; col++)
            {
                cout << keyword << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }

        return 0;
}

bool correct_keyword(char keyword)
{
    bool correct = false;
    if (keyword != correct)
        return true;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

If my keyword was "Fish" it would look something like this:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   F   I   S   H   A
1   B   C   D   E   G
2   J   K   L   M   N
3   O   P   Q   R   T
4   U   V   W   X   Y
```

Any help would be appreciated!! Thank you very much!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Well just having the right format for printing out a 2-D array is what i have so far

Comment: It would be better if you could show the code you've written.

Comment: There's a sample of what I have done so far

Comment: Is `"hello"` considered invalid keyword because it has duplicate `'l'` characters? Also would `"wizard"` be invalid keyword because it contains `'z'`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already declared the alphabet in the 2D array (5x5), let's say in `char alphabet[5][5]`, you can print these values using nested for loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        std::cout << alphabet[i][j] << std::endl;
```

The code will print all letters in new lines, if you need to print them as a 5x5 array, then this should work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        std::cout << alphabet[i][j] << " "; // separate letters with a space
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Okay. So it worked. But how do I print a keyword into the array as well.

Comment: For writing the alphabet you could use the loop I've written, but instead of using  `std::cout` for printing letters, you should use `alphabet[i][j] = 'a' + i * 5 + j;` (as you can add integers to characters to move by ASCII values). When it comes to your own words, you have to modify both loops, so `i` and `j` are some given starting values, but be careful to input only letters which are in your word, also do not try to place long words at the end, so you do not exceed the memory assigned to your array.

Comment: How would I put it in the above work I've done so far?

Comment: I did not notice how the alphabet has changed, I'm sorry for that. I would actually have an array of `bool`, which would store information whether the letter has been used or not, then after the word was placed to the array (each letter one by one, changing bool value of corresponding value of the letter - assuming a=0, b=1,...) I would start inserting the alphabet using `alphabet[i][j] = 'a' + i * 5 + j`, but after checking if the letter we want to set was already used or not.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `std::string` to store you keyword? That provides `.find()` to check whether a character is included. You don't have to worry about a 2D array, all you need is your `std::string` and a counter and you can output the `'\n'` after every 5<sup>th</sup> character providing your output in a 5x5 grid.

How do you handle keywords with duplicate characters? Are they just considered invalid keywords? What about `"wizard"` would it likewise be an invalid keyword because it contains the excluded `'z'` character? (I guess both would have to be, otherwise you would not be able to fill though `'y'` in your 5x5 grid)

With that said, you could simply take your keyword as the first argument to your program and keep a counter of the number of characters output and do something simple like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define WIDTH 5

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    std::string s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "help";
    size_t n = 0;
```

Now you need to check whether your keyword is valid, no duplicate characters and no `'z'`, e.g.

```
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size() - 1; i++)   /* check for duplicate chars */
        if (s.find(s.at(i), i+1) != std::string::npos) {
            std::cerr << "error: '" << s.at(i) << "' duplcate char.\n";
            return 1;
        }
    if (s.find('z') != std::string::npos) {     /* check for 'z' in input */
        std::cerr << "error: input contains 'z'.\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

All that is left is outputting your keyword, followed by the remaining characters in the alphabet (minus `'z'`). You can do that with two loops, e.g.

```
    for (; n < s.size(); n++) {     /* output keyword, keep n as count */
        if (n && n % WIDTH == 0)    /* impose WIDTH no. chars per-line */
            std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << " " << s.at(n);
    }


    for (int i = 'a'; i < 'z'; i++) {   /* output alphabet, skipping chars */
        if (s.find((char)i) == std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << " " << (char)i;
            n++;
            if (n && n % WIDTH == 0)
                std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
```

(**note:** the above uses *lowercase* characters, but you can simply change to *uppercase* if that is a requirement by swapping characters)

Putting it altogether, you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define WIDTH 5

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    std::string s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "help";
    size_t n = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size() - 1; i++)   /* check for duplicate chars */
        if (s.find(s.at(i), i+1) != std::string::npos) {
            std::cerr << "error: '" << s.at(i) << "' duplcate char.\n";
            return 1;
        }
    if (s.find('z') != std::string::npos) {     /* check for 'z' in input */
        std::cerr << "error: input contains 'z'.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    for (; n < s.size(); n++) {     /* output keyword, keep n as count */
        if (n && n % WIDTH == 0)    /* impose WIDTH no. chars per-line */
            std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << " " << s.at(n);
    }


    for (int i = 'a'; i < 'z'; i++) {   /* output alphabet, skipping chars */
        if (s.find((char)i) == std::string::npos) {
            std::cout << " " << (char)i;
            n++;
            if (n && n % WIDTH == 0)
                std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

(**note:** adding any surrounding Row or Column Headings, e.g. `"0 1 2 3 4"` is left to you)

**Example Use/Output**

With default `"help"` as keyword:

```
$ ./bin/alphabet
 h e l p a
 b c d f g
 i j k m n
 o q r s t
 u v w x y
```

With `"absent"` as keyword:

```
$ ./bin/alphabet absent
 a b s e n
 t c d f g
 h i j k l
 m o p q r
 u v w x y
```

Or an invalid keyword:

```
$ ./bin/alphabet hello
error: 'l' duplcate char.
```

You are free to use a 2D array, but it just seems like that would complicate input and storage of the keyword. Look things over and let me know if something like this would work and whether you have any further questions.